# LED panel wire connection space

Tags: led, junction

I'm replacing old 2x2 fluorescent drop ceiling lights with LED panels. The space provided to contain the wire nuts and connections is super small. Its a 10Lbs in a 2Lb bag kind of situation. In total, I've over 100 panels to replace. I don't know if I should just add a junction box for each panel and drop one feed down to each one. or look for another LED panel with a larger enclosure.
[image]

[image]

Comment: How much space is there to the left? This doesn't look that bad, really. With a bit of planning and careful laying-in I think you can avoid the whole extra box thing.

Comment: Very little space, less than a 1/2in. If I trimmed the 12/2 short and was very careful, I might be able to STUFF everything in. It just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the normal way to do that, which your LED vendor was expecting you to do.

Bring your Romex cables into a 4 x 4 x 1-1/2" metal box ($1) attached to the actual ceiling.  Sheath must extend at least 1/4" beyond the cable clamp.  Wires must extend at least 6" beyond end of sheath.   Box must be within 5' of the light's attach box.

Install a 10-32 ground screw in the ground screw site on the metal box.  Both Romex grounds ground there.  (in metal boxes always ground the box *first*).

Get a pre-made metal jacketed wire whip, or make one out of AC cable and knockout fittings. If it has a ground wire, you got MC cable by mistake.  Must be <6' long so the shell can provide ground.

Up in the box, do the expected thing.  Fit a blank junction box cover.

Down in the LED fixture, splice hot and neutral.  Ground is delivered via the cable shell and properly fit connector, so it doesn't take any space in the box.